# Regex to extract lines between specific strings

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract the lines between two specific strings. 
Example:

```
---Title---
Header 1: 

Sample text. Multiple lines

Header 2: 

Sample Text
```

Here I need to extract all the lines between `Header 1:` & `Header 2:`. 
I tried with `/^Header 1:(?s)(.*)Header 2:/i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a regexp, using the function explode : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Example :

```
$str = "---Title---
Header 1: 

Sample text. Multiple lines

Header 2: 

Sample Text";

$str=explode("Header 1:", $str)[1];
$str=explode("Header 2:", $str)[0];
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regexp for this, you'll need to use the correct regexp modifiers:

- m : PCRE_MULTILINE
- s : PCRE_DOTALL

See docs here:

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

```
<?php

$str = file_get_contents('sample.txt');
echo $str;

if (preg_match('/Header 1:\s*(.*)Header 2:/msi', $str, $matches))
{
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```